# How to create a custom info window for google maps?

Tags: java, android

I am **trying to create my own info window**, but **when I run it I have these errors**:

> error: cannot find symbol variable LatLng
>
> error: cannot find symbol method getPosition()
>
> error: non-static variable latitude cannot be referenced from a static context
>
> error: non-static variable longitude cannot be referenced from a static context
>
> error: cannot find symbol class atLng
>
> Error: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. Compilation failed; see the compiler
>   error output for details.

**This is the code I am using:**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptor;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;




public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private GoogleMap mMap1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap1 = googleMap;
        if(mMap1 != null){
            mMap1.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter(){

            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                  return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window, null);
                TextView tvLocality = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_locality);
                TextView tvLat = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_lat);
                TextView tvLng = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_lng);
                TextView tvSnippet = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_snippet);

               LatLng = mMap1.getPosition();
                tvLocality.setText(marker.getTitle());
                tvLat.setText("Latitudine: " + LatLng.latitude);
                tvLng.setText("Longitudine: " + LatLng.longitude);
                tvSnippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());

                return v;
            }
            });


            }


          atLng biss = new LatLng(45.758035, 21.227514);
        mMap1.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(biserica)
                .title("Church")
                .snippet("gafhha")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory. fromResource(R.drawable.marker)));
        mMap1.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(biss, 14));
 }
}
```

**and info_window.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/marker"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_locality"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_lat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_lng"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_snippet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Does anyone know whats wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your code:**

```
LatLng = mMap1.getPosition();
            tvLocality.setText(marker.getTitle());
            tvLat.setText("Latitudine: " + LatLng.latitude);
            tvLng.setText("Longitudine: " + LatLng.longitude);
            tvSnippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());
```

**What you were done wrong**

> Didn't declare variable for LatLng

should be **LatLng latlng=....**

> mMap1 will not have getposition()

you should add **marker.getPosition();**

> same for LatLng.latitude you have to use **latlng.latitude**

**Modified code**

```
 LatLng latlng= marker.getPosition();
                tvLocality.setText(marker.getTitle());
                tvLat.setText("Latitudine: " + latlng.latitude);
                tvLng.setText("Longitudine: " + latlng.longitude);
                tvSnippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());
```

**other error at**

```
atLng biss = new LatLng(45.758035, 21.227514);
    mMap1.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(biserica)
            .title("Church")
            .snippet("gafhha")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory. fromResource(R.drawable.marker)));
    mMap1.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(biss, 14));
```

**change it to**

change **atLng** to **LatLng**

change **biserica** to **biss**

```
LatLng biss = new LatLng(45.758035, 21.227514);
    mMap1.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(biss)
            .title("Church")
            .snippet("gafhha")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory. fromResource(R.drawable.marker)));
    mMap1.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(biss, 14));
```

Comment: Thank you a lot !

Comment: Can you tell me how to make a fullscreen infoWindow when you click on infoWindow ?